# How to access .file format?

Tags: mysql, sql-server

> I have exported the database from SQL server and the file which got
>   downloaded is of .file extension. Now how can I access that file and
>   even how to import the file in the MySQL.

Comment: It depends what the file contains. If you exported only the data in CSV format then you can use [`mysqlimport`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqlimport.html) to import it into MySQL. The file extension doesn't matter. Or course, you have to create the table in advance.

Comment: What's actually in the file? How did you export it?

Comment: I have exported the database from MSSQL and it got saved as .FILE format.

Answer (score -1):

MySQL known this file automatically or you can change the file extension manually from Terminal or CMD Panel

CMD -> ren yourfile.file yourfile.sql

Terminal -> for file in *.dat; do mv "$file" "${file%dat}mp3"; done

Than Import your MySQL file to database!